# Native C++ program crashes on startup with C++/CLI & C# interop DLL

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, c++-cli

I'm in a situation where I need to wrap C# WPF UserControls in a C++/CLI wrapper to use in a native C++ program. The native program uses MFC heavily and is compiled in VS2010. I've properly generated the C++/CLI .lib and .dll files in a separate solution and linked to them from the MFC application, which compiles and links successfully, generating the executable as usual. However, when I go to launch the MFC application, I get an access violation error 0xc0000005 before it even gets to main(). When I comment out the wrapper code, the program launches normally.

To try and isolate the problem, I tried creating a completely separate native C++ project whose sole purpose is to call the wrapper class with dummy data. This project reaches main() but throws an exception (0xe0434352) when I call the constructor for the wrapper class.

I've tried searching for any possible solutions, but the one the most closely matches my situation says to check the function signatures to make sure I'm passing in the right number of arguments (I am). I've also looked up the 0xe0434352 exception from the standalone project and it appears to be a generic .NET exception.

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29918179/wrapping-interop-hwndsource-in-c-cli-to-be-used-in-native-c-mfc-applicatio) question posted, but was hoping the solution would be simpler than that. I've been following the instructions on [this](http://pragmateek.com/using-c-from-native-c-with-the-help-of-ccli-v2/) blog to create the wrapper class.

I'm including all code but the MFC application code, since it's not even loading to main(). I'm hoping that if I can manage to resolve the issue in the brand new project, the MFC application will start.

C# WPF:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ManagedWPFLink
{
    public struct TestResultData
    {
        public string inspectionType;
        public string testResult;
        public string measuredValue;
        public string passCondition;
        public string comments;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for TestResultsDialog.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class TestResultsDialog : UserControl
    {
        private Window window;

        public TestResultsDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataGridTextColumn col1 = new DataGridTextColumn();
            DataGridTextColumn col2 = new DataGridTextColumn();
            DataGridTextColumn col3 = new DataGridTextColumn();
            DataGridTextColumn col4 = new DataGridTextColumn();
            DataGridTextColumn col5 = new DataGridTextColumn();

            this.testResultsGrid.Columns.Add(col1);
            this.testResultsGrid.Columns.Add(col2);
            this.testResultsGrid.Columns.Add(col3);
            this.testResultsGrid.Columns.Add(col4);
            this.testResultsGrid.Columns.Add(col5);

            col1.Binding = new Binding("inspectionType");
            col2.Binding = new Binding("testResult");
            col3.Binding = new Binding("measuredValue");
            col4.Binding = new Binding("passCondition");
            col5.Binding = new Binding("comments");

            col1.Header = "Inspection Type";
            col2.Header = "Test Result";
            col3.Header = "Measured Value";
            col4.Header = "Pass Condition";
            col5.Header = "Comments";

            this.window = new Window
            {
                Title = "Inspection Results",
                Content = this,
                SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight,
                ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize
            };
        }

        public void addRow(string inspectionType, string testResult, string measuredValue, string passCondition, string comments)
        {
            TestResultData data = new TestResultData();

            data.inspectionType = inspectionType;
            data.testResult = testResult;
            data.measuredValue = measuredValue;
            data.passCondition = passCondition;
            data.comments = comments;

            this.testResultsGrid.Items.Add(data);
        }

        public void deleteAllRows()
        {
            this.testResultsGrid.Items.Clear();
        }

        public void showDialog()
        {
            this.window.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

C# XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="ManagedWPFLink.TestResultsDialog"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="600">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="376" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="testResultsGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="576" ItemsSource="{Binding}" MinColumnWidth="40">
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C++/CLI header:

```
// ManagedWPFLink.h

#pragma once

namespace WPFLink 
{
    class WPFPrivate;

    class __declspec(dllexport) WPFWrapper
    {
    private:
        WPFPrivate *internalWrapper;

    public:
        WPFWrapper();
        ~WPFWrapper();

        void addItems(const char **data);
        void deleteAllRows();
        void showDialog();
    };
}
```

C++/CLI source:

```
// This is the main DLL file.

#include "stdafx.h"

#using <WindowsBase.dll>
#using <PresentationCore.dll>
#using <PresentationFramework.dll>

#using "ManagedWPFLink.dll"

#include "WPFLink.h"

using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace WPFLink
{
    public class WPFPrivate
    {
    public:
        msclr::auto_gcroot<System::String^> inspectionType;
        msclr::auto_gcroot<System::String^> testResult;
        msclr::auto_gcroot<System::String^> measuredValue;
        msclr::auto_gcroot<System::String^> passCondition;
        msclr::auto_gcroot<System::String^> comments;

        msclr::auto_gcroot<ManagedWPFLink::TestResultsDialog^> testResultDialog;

    public:
        WPFPrivate()
        {
        }

        ~WPFPrivate()
        {
            delete testResultDialog;
        }
    };

    WPFWrapper::WPFWrapper()
    {
        this->internalWrapper = new WPFLink::WPFPrivate();
    }

    WPFWrapper::~WPFWrapper()
    {
        delete this->internalWrapper;
    }

    void WPFWrapper::addItems(const char **data)
    {
        this->internalWrapper->inspectionType = gcnew System::String(data[0]);
        this->internalWrapper->testResult = gcnew System::String(data[1]);
        this->internalWrapper->measuredValue = gcnew System::String(data[2]);
        this->internalWrapper->passCondition = gcnew System::String(data[3]);
        this->internalWrapper->comments = gcnew System::String(data[4]);

        this->internalWrapper->testResultDialog->addRow(this->internalWrapper->inspectionType, this->internalWrapper->testResult,
            this->internalWrapper->measuredValue, this->internalWrapper->passCondition, this->internalWrapper->comments);
    }

    void WPFWrapper::deleteAllRows()
    {
        this->internalWrapper->testResultDialog->deleteAllRows();
    }

    void WPFWrapper::showDialog()
    {
        this->internalWrapper->testResultDialog->showDialog();
    }
}
```

Native C++ code:

```
#include "..\WPFLink\WPFLink.h"

int main()
{
    WPFLink::WPFWrapper wrapper; // Generates 0xe0434352 error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stepping through the native version with the VS debugger gives no useful information?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed delete an `auto_gcroot` object like you're doing in ~WPFPrivate()... auto_gcroot does its own resource management. I'd also try commenting out that fancy TestResultsDialog in WPFPrivate to see if that's causing the problem or if it's something more fundamental.

Comment: @user4581301 Stepping through the native version with the VS debugger gives the error mentioned in the comment whether I "step over" or "step into" that line. Nothing else useful.

Comment: @MarkWaterman I'll try removing the delete statement and see if that helps. Commenting out the TestResultsDialog probably won't be useful, since that's the object I'm trying to interact with for this interop layer.

Comment: Confirming that commenting out the TestResultsDialog in WPFPrivate prevented the system from crashing. I need to figure out either why it's crashing or how to properly wrap WPF for use in MFC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much hair-pulling, I resorted to using the method in this post here: http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_managed/nfc/article.php/c14589/Hosting-WPF-Content-in-an-MFC-Application.htm

I used the relevant code to generate an HWND and the program worked flawlessly with my own native C++ code. However, I'm still running into an access violation on startup in our main MFC application which I haven't managed to narrow down at all. The only information I have is that if I attempt to link to my DLL at all, the program crashes. I will have to abandon this method of linking to a stub .lib file and loading the necessary DLL and instead redo the interface to only use *extern "C"* functions and manually call LoadLibrary on my DLL.

Thanks everyone who tried to help.